# Unable to use custom Class Library (DLL) in PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I have below Class Library developed for writing Thread Safe logs in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ThreadSafeLogger
{
    public class ThreadSafeLogger
    {
        private static readonly string ApplicationLogFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ApplicationLogFilePath");
        private static readonly string Updated_ApplicationLogFilePath = ApplicationLogFilePath.EndsWith("\\") ? ApplicationLogFilePath : $"{ApplicationLogFilePath}\\";
        private static readonly long LogFile_MaxSizeInBytes = 5242880; // 5 MB
        private static readonly string TSLogFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TSLogFileName");
        private static readonly string TSLogFilePath = $"{Updated_ApplicationLogFilePath}{TSLogFileName}";

        static readonly TextWriter tw;

        static ThreadSafeLogger()
        {
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    FileInfo logFileInfo = new FileInfo(TSLogFilePath);

                    if (logFileInfo.FullName.EndsWith("\\") || string.IsNullOrEmpty(logFileInfo.Name) || !Regex.IsMatch(TSLogFilePath, @"[A-z]:[\\](?:\w+[\\])+(\w+\.(?:([tT][xX][tT]|[lL][oO][gG])))"))
                    {
                        // Give a correct file name
                        TSLogFilePath = $"{Updated_ApplicationLogFilePath}TSLog.log";

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // Give a correct file name
                    TSLogFilePath = $"{Updated_ApplicationLogFilePath}TSLog.log";
                }

                tw = TextWriter.Synchronized(File.AppendText(TSLogFilePath));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message + " > GlobalHelper > ThreadSafeLogger()");
            }
        }

        public static void WriteTSLog(string VerboseText)
        {
            DateTime TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;

            // Create a backup of existing log file if size is more than 1048576 bytes (1mb)
            try
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(TSLogFilePath);
                if (fileInfo.Length > LogFile_MaxSizeInBytes)
                {
                    File.Copy(TSLogFilePath, $"{Updated_ApplicationLogFilePath}BACKUP_{TSLogFileName}", true);
                    File.Delete(TSLogFilePath);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message + " > GlobalHelper > WriteTSLog()");
            }

            try
            {
                if (!File.Exists(TSLogFilePath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Updated_ApplicationLogFilePath);
                }

                TSLog($"[{TimeStamp:dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}] {VerboseText}", tw);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application"))
                    {
                        eventLog.Source = "Application";
                        eventLog.WriteEntry($"ThreadSafeLogger: failed to write to log file '{TSLogFilePath}'.{Environment.NewLine}Message:'[{TimeStamp:dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}] {VerboseText}'.{Environment.NewLine}Reason: {ex.Message}", EventLogEntryType.Error, 2204);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine($"[{TimeStamp:dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}] {VerboseText}");
                }
            }
        }

        private static readonly object _syncObject = new object();

        private static void TSLog(string LogMessage, TextWriter w)
        {
            try
            {
                lock (_syncObject)
                {
                    w.WriteLine(LogMessage);
                    w.Flush();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine($"Error in TSLog(): {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine when I call it from any other application. However, it is failing when I am calling this from PowerShell:

```
Add-Type -Path .\ThreadSafeLogger.dll

[ThreadSafeLogger.ThreadSafeLogger]::WriteTSLog("Test")
```

Throws below error:

```
Exception calling "WriteTSLog" with "1" argument(s): "The type initializer for 'ThreadSafeLogger.ThreadSafeLogger' threw an exception."
At line:1 char:1
+ [ThreadSafeLogger.ThreadSafeLogger]::WriteTSLog("Test")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeInitializationException
```

I have tested this from another Console Application by referencing the same DLL and it is working:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LibTester
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] WeekDays = new[] { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
            _ = Parallel.ForEach(WeekDays, Weekday => {
                ThreadSafeLogger.ThreadSafeLogger.WriteTSLog($"Started working on {Weekday}");
                Thread.Sleep(250);
                ThreadSafeLogger.ThreadSafeLogger.WriteTSLog($"Finished working on {Weekday}");
            });

            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output in log file:

```
[14-Oct-2022 15:22:20.647954] Started working on Monday
[14-Oct-2022 15:22:20.647954] Started working on Saturday
[14-Oct-2022 15:22:20.647954] Started working on Sunday
[14-Oct-2022 15:22:20.647954] Started working on Wednesday
[14-Oct-2022 15:22:20.647954] Started working on Friday
[14-Oct-2022 15:22:20.647954] Started working on Tuesday
[14-Oct-2022 15:22:20.647954] Started working on Thursday
[14-Oct-2022 15:22:20.918791] Finished working on Friday
[14-Oct-2022 15:22:20.918791] Finished working on Monday
[14-Oct-2022 15:22:20.918791] Finished working on Wednesday
[14-Oct-2022 15:22:20.918791] Finished working on Thursday
[14-Oct-2022 15:22:20.918856] Finished working on Sunday
[14-Oct-2022 15:22:20.918856] Finished working on Tuesday
[14-Oct-2022 15:22:20.918791] Finished working on Saturday
```

Comment: Which version of PowerShell and .NET are you using?

Comment: Your logic depends on configuration file which is missing in PowerShell context. Error suggests some static initialization. I bet 'ConfigurationManager.AppSettings' is throwing exception thus  type can't be initialized.

Comment: Configuration file is kept in the same folder as DLL

Comment: @Pawel Dyl: I am using PowerShell 5.1

Comment: Just because PowerShell has been told to load your dll from a specific path, doesn't mean it knows to look in the same place for the configuration file. The application path will be PowerShell's and that knows nothing of the configuration.

Comment: What happens when you debug the dll? You can attach the VS debugger to the Powershell process, then import the dll and run your code.

Comment: @bluuf: On server where I am running this, there is no VS available.

Comment: @Ash: is there a way to handle this?

Comment: In that case I'd advise you to debug the dll on another machine. You should never put untested code into production in my opinion.

Comment: I've been noticing that types are different in powershell from c#.  That to get powershell to run I have to keep on casting object to the same type as in c#.  I've been usining Gettype() in both c# and powershell and comparing, then cast my powershell object to match same type as c#.

Comment: @bluuf: As I mentioned, I am able to test the dll in another console application by importing the dll in the project and it was working on my dev laptop

Comment: Yes, provide a method to read them from a particular location, file or provide them in the DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the experts who have commented. I have hard-coded the file-path and file name in the DLL code and it is not giving any errors any more:

```
    private static readonly string ApplicationLogFilePath = @"C:\Temp\ThreadSafeLogs\";//ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ApplicationLogFilePath");
    private static readonly string Updated_ApplicationLogFilePath = ApplicationLogFilePath.EndsWith("\\") ? ApplicationLogFilePath : $"{ApplicationLogFilePath}\\";
    private static readonly long LogFile_MaxSizeInBytes = 5242880; // 5 MB
    private static readonly string TSLogFileName = "TSLog.log";// ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TSLogFileName");
    private static readonly string TSLogFilePath = $"{Updated_ApplicationLogFilePath}{TSLogFileName}";
```